# CM3+ and RaspiCam V2 issues

Tags: camera, raspicam, compute-module-3, compute-module, compute-module-development-kit

I'm trying to use two RaspiCam V2 with CM3+ and Computer Module 3+ Development Kit board.
I followed instructions provided in official links:

- [Raspberry Pi OS with desktop and recommended software](https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/operating-systems/#raspberry-pi-os-32-bit)
- [CM3+ EMMC OS flashing](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/computemodule/cm-emmc-flashing.md)

and then I followed camera setup procedure provided [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/computemodule/cmio-camera.md). As a first try I focused on single camera procedure, unluckly I immediately stumbled on a first issue:

[image: first issue]

On the official forum I found a matching solution [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=183038), but following it I got this:

[image: second issue]

It seems that camera is not found and moreover that I2C bus is supposed to be on GPIO 2 and 3 while the procedure was asking to connect wires on GPIO 0 and 1:
I connected bus wires on GPIO 2 and 3 and made a check over I2C trough the following command:

```
sudo i2c-detect -y 1
```

now it seems that camera is found (If I'm understanding the following message correctly):

[image: i2c-detect result]

but even with such wiring I'm not able to complete the camera setup procedure because I alway got the first message (first issue picture).

--- UPDATE [as request by Dirk] ---

This's the content of config.txt (pretty stock):

```
# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

[pi4]
# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver on top of the dispmanx display stack
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

[all]
#dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
start_x=1
gpu_mem=128
```

Is there a way to fix this and make raspicam working with CM3+ ?

Please note that I'm using two different camera units (both RaspiCam V2) and different sets of cables/adapters but I always got the same error.

Comment: Pls post the contents of config.txt (remove all empty and commented out lines)

Comment: I left it untouched (but I'm going to paste it here asap)

Comment: @Dirk ... Config.txt (posted)